# Send a string between sockets in between bytes

Tags: java, android, sockets, stream

I have 2 sockets connecting and sending a file. I want at some point send a signal to the second socket. I thought of sending a string "start" and when the receiver socket gets it, I execute something. Below is the code for receiver and sender. What am I doing wrong? The receiver never gets the "start" and I am sure its being sent. Thanks

Sender Side:

```
byte[] buff = new byte[1024 * 50];    
while (isRunning && (readBytes = data.read(buff, 0, buff.length)) != -1) {
    client.getOutputStream().write(buff, 0, readBytes);
    if(sendStart){
        client.getOutputStream().("start".getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, "start".getBytes("UTF-8").length);
        sendStart = false;
    }
}
```

Receiver Side:

```
DataInputStream in = null;
   try {
        in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
     } catch (IOException e) {
   }

byte buffer[] = new byte[1024 * 50]; 
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    String received = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    if(received!=null && received.equals("start")){
        Log.d(TAG,"received start");
        //do something
    }
    receivedFile.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

Comment: what is `in`? any error?

Comment: @njzk2 in is the DataInputStream (I edited the question). No error. The received string is gibberish.

Comment: you start by sending the content of `data` what is that for?

Comment: @njzk2 data is InputStream from a video. Scenario is while sending the video, at a certain point I want to tell the other socket to start playing the video for example.

Comment: but you are writing to the same outputstream. how do you expect your client to receive only the "start" command, without the data?

Comment: @njzk2 No I am expecting to receive the "start" in the middle of the stream and detect it.

Comment: The problem is that there is no reason why your buffer should contain just "start", with nothing before or after, nor why it should contain the whole "start" string, as opposed to just the first letter first, because you are reading and writing in chunks of unspecified size.

Comment: @njzk2 I just need a signal, doesn't have to be "start". But one letter is too short, there is a probability that other bytes can be read as "s" for example.

Comment: similarly to FTP, I would suggest using a second socket to transmit the command.

Comment: One other way would be to send your command twice, and search for it in your received string. (send "startstart", and use  `received.contains("start"), this way you know that one "start" complete needs to be in one of the frames, unless your frames are really short)

Comment: If you are going to have embedded commands you need an escape convention for when the command appears in the data, and for the escape convention itself ditto. Another technique would be to send type-length-value message: DATA-length-file_data or SIGNAL-length-"START" for example, where DATA and SIGNAL are byte values.

Comment: Debug len=in.read() value a num of bytes read, use new String(buffer, "ISO-8859-1", len) and scan for start substring or better scan a buffer for 's','t','a','r','t' bytes from 0...len bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error might be in here:

```
client.getOutputStream().("start".getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, "start".getBytes("UTF-8").length);
```

if you look, the `write()` method isn't anywhere on this line.
also, I wanted to ask, is there a particular reason you're handling the string serialization yourself? you could use something like `PrintWriter` and `Scanner` for strings, or you could use `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` for any kind of object.